# Chrome Form Submit POST Data View Source Not Working

Tags: html, google-chrome, postdata, view-source

See these Code and debug in chrome

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
   { 
   echo "<form method='POST'><input type=submit name='submit'></form>"; 
   } else { 
   echo "You Can't view the source of THIS LINE using Chrome."; 
   }   
?>
```

When i press submit button in chrome and then i right click on page i can't view source of the page i think chrome refetch whole data. but same thing work in all browser...
Any idea Suggestion....
To Make Work in Chrome ...